# Imported Library Header class not Available?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, header-files

[image]

this is my linked libraries 
[image]

AVFoundation/AVFoundation is there ,but i can't import header files,i don't know why ?

Comment: have you added in linked frameworks ?

Comment: yes i have added eventhough its giving error @MayankPatel

Comment: `#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>` try this

Comment: ok wait a minute @MayankPatel

Comment: @MayankPatel yes its working ,may i know why its happening

Comment: check my answer in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the Project in the Project Navigator

Select the Build Phases tab and expand Link Binary With Libraries.

[image]

[image]

Your import statement should look like this, you have import wrong player in place of `AVPlayer` you have to use `AVAudioPlayer`

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>  // Add player
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unnecessary to import again,this header file `AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h` has import everything you may need.

[image: screenshot]